# Why is $PSScriptRoot referencing itself?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm in PowerShell ISE and `$roster = Import-Csv '$PSScriptRoot\Company Roster.csv'` returns the error

```
Import-Csv : Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\\Desktop\Change\
$PSScriptRoot\Company Roster.csv'.
At C:\Users\\Desktop\Change\Form.ps1:30 char:15
+     $roster = Import-Csv '$PSScriptRoot\Company Roster.csv'
```

Why is `$PSScriptRoot` seemingly including its own variable name in its reference?

Comment: The documentation is helpful. Run `help about_Quoting_Rules`.

Answer (score 3):

No, the variable does not include itself. You just put it in single quotes, which prevent variable expansion, so your script is looking for a file with the *literal* name `$PSScriptRoot\Company Roster.csv` in the current working directory.

Change the single quotes to double quotes, and the problem will disappear.

```
$roster = Import-Csv "$PSScriptRoot\Company Roster.csv"
```

Comment: I originally had that and it threw the error `Import-Csv : Could not find file 'C:\Company Roster.csv` (and still does) which is why I changed it to something I seemingly had more luck with.

Comment: @Ryan `$PSScriptRoot` is an automatic variable (introduced with PowerShell v3 IIRC), which always should contain the path to the directory containing the current script. The error you showed should only appear if you're using the variable directly in the PowerShell console (where it's undefined) rather than a script, and with the working directory being C:\. Did you try starting the PowerShell console without profiles (`powershell.exe -NoProfile`)?